# How to compile and execute typescript files using 1 command only?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I know that TS is converted to JS using `tsc`

Then after we get `.js`, we execute the `.js` file using `node`.

These are 2 steps in order to execute a `.ts` file

My question is, **how to do it in 1 step?** (like one command instead of 2(`tsc` and `node`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ts-node` which will run ts files.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node